# How do I attach a 58mm solar filter to my lens?

Tags: filters, filter-diameter

I have a Nikon D3100. I have a 58mm solar lens I am trying to attach to the camera. What step up ring adapter would I need? A 52mm to 58mm?
Also would like to be able to attach to a Nikon ED AF-S Nikkor 70-300mm 1:4.5-5.6 G VR Nikon SWM VR ED IF 67. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By "solar lens", do you mean a dark filter for taking photographs of the sun?

Comment: By 58mm do you mean a spin-on type filter with 58mm threads? Or a slip on type filter designed primarily for telescopes with a maximum exterior width of 58mm?

Comment: I'm a cheap b***d, so I bought a sheet of solar-filter plastic & sandwiched it between the lens and a plain old "UV filter" glass filter.

Comment: Yes...I already have the solar lens which is 58mm...

Comment: LOL...I do like cheap...but already have the solar lens

Comment: Yes...a spin on type

Comment: Or maybe I need a step down?

Answer (score 2):

> What step up ring adapter would I need?

Look at the front of the lens on your camera. There should be a mark like this: ⌀ Next to that, you'll find a measurement in millimeters, for example: `⌀ 52mm` That indicates the diameter of the filter threads on your lens. If that diameter doesn't match the filter you want to use, like your solar filter, then you'll need an adapter ring with male threads that match your lens's filter diameter and female threads that match the filter you want to use.

It looks like your [AF-S Nikkor 70-300mm 1:4.5-5.6 G VR](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003ZSHNCC) has a 58mm filter diameter, so if your solar filter is also 58mm, then you don't need any adapter ring at all -- just line up the threads and gently screw the filter onto the front of the lens. If you're not sure how to do that, get a knowledgeable friend to show you.

Comment: Thanks for your input...the AF-S Nikkor 70-300mm has a 67mm I believe...

Comment: @Gregsed56 Looks like there are at least two different Nikkor 70-300mm zooms listed on Amazon. I got the 58mm number from the linked page, and [here](https://www.amazon.com/Nikon-NIKKOR-70-300mm-4-5-6-3G-Cameras/dp/B01KJ8UMKK) is another also with 58mm filter diameter, but I do also see one with a 62mm filter diameter and another with 67mm filter diameter. Given that, it's really best to just look at the front of the lens in your hands. ;-)

Comment: @Gregsed56 You can buy a [58-67mm step *down* ring](https://www.amazon.com/Bower-Step-Down-Adapter-Ring-Filter/dp/B0002HMRJS) to attach a 58mm filter to lens with 67mm filter threads, but keep in mind that this will reduce the light entering the lens and possibly cause vignetting. Considering that you're using a solar filter, maybe that's not a bad thing, and step rings are a lot cheaper than new filters, but just know that in general step *down* rings aren't the optimal solution.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments...really appreciate you all.